# Generate an IPA without Apple ID using Crashlytics beta

Tags: ios, crashlytics, twitter-fabric, crashlytics-beta

I want to confirm Is there are way to generate IPA without Apple ID using Crashlytics beta ?

Answer (score 1):

No, Without Apple ID it is not possible to create IPA files in iOS. Because you need provisioning profile and signing certificate to archive the build.

Create an Apple account, it will take 4-5 days to activate. Then create your certificate and provisioning profile to make the IPA file.